# Accessing javascript menu by selenium webDriver

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I want to click the 'CookBooks' in following menu by using selenium web driver. It is appearing hovering the mouse and it is a javascript menu. Please help me . Following is the html view of that menu.

```
<li>
<a href="#">
<span>Set Up</span>
</a>
    <ul>
    <li>
        <a onclick="validateLevelOfOwnership('MaintainCookbook.html');return false;" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <span>Cookbooks</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a onclick="validateLevelOfOwnership('MaintainCategories.html');return false;" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <span>Categories</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a onclick="validateLevelOfOwnership('MaintainDistributors.html');return false;" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <span>Distributors</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/recipeManager/distributorItem/listItems.action">
        <span>Distributor Items</span>
        </a>
    </li>
        <li>
        <a onclick="validateLevelOfOwnership('MaintainPreparationMethodsAndConversions.html');return false;" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <span>Prep Methods & Conversion Ratios</span>
        </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following code,

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Cookbooks")).click();
```

This can be used to click on **text which represents links**..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'Actions' class here to emulate the user gestures.

Below is the code I wrote to perform a menu click wherein we need to first hover the mouse over root menu and then click the sub-menu. For illustration purpose, I've taken the site : http://www.milonic.com/menusample15.php.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.milonic.com/menusample15.php");

    //element refering to 'Milonic' menu
    WebElement rootMenu = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Milonic"));

    Actions action = new Actions(driver);

    //move to 'Milonic' first
    action.moveToElement(rootMenu).perform();
    //wait for the sub-menu to come up
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    //inside sub-menu click on 'FAQ'
    action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("FAQ"))).click().perform();
}
```